# Validate Modified Model Using Annotations in EntityFramwork and ASPNET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, validation, model

I have this class as a part of EF Model:

```
class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage="Name cannot be more than 100 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this method in my controller:

```
public IActionResult ChangeName(int id, string name) {
    var person = db.Persons.Find(id);
    if(person == null) return NotFound();
    person.Name = name;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new {result = "Saved Successfully"});
}
```

Is there any way to validate `person` after changing the `Name` property using the annotation `MaxLength` rather than manually check for it. Becuase sometimes I might have more than one validation and I don't want to examine each one of them. Also, I might change these parameters in the future (e.g. make the max length 200), and that means I have to change it everywhere else.

So is it possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly, but normally you would try-catch `SaveChanges` and intercept `DbEntityValidationException`s. They show you what's wrong.

Comment: You can also call `db.GetValidationErrors()`.

Comment: @GertArnold If I used DbEntityValidationException, then how would I display the message: "Name cannot be more than 100 characters"

Comment: The message is in the Exception (just inspect its properties). But how to display it is your choice. Just as you display any message I guess. In ASP.Net MVC it's all integrated in the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution to my problem, I created a method that takes the model and checks for errors:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> ValidateModel(Person model)
{
    var errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (var attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes())
        {
            var validationAttribute = attribute as ValidationAttribute;
            if(validationAttribute == null) continue;
            var value = property.GetValue(model);
            if (!validationAttribute.IsValid(value))
            {
                errors.Add(property.Name, validationAttribute.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As stated by @Gert Arnold, the method above returns only one validation per property. Below is the fixed version which returns a list of errors for each property

```
public static IDictionary<string, IList<string>> ValidateModel(Person model)
{
    var errors = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
    foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (var attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes())
        {
            var validationAttribute = attribute as ValidationAttribute;
            if (validationAttribute == null) continue;
            var value = property.GetValue(model);
            if (validationAttribute.IsValid(value)) continue;
            if (!errors.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                errors[property.Name] = new List<string>();
            errors[property.Name].Add(validationAttribute.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method works as long as there is one validation error per property. Also, it's quite elaborate. You can use `db.GetValidationErrors()` to get the same result. One difference is that errors are collected in a collection per property name:

```
var errors = db.GetValidationErrors()
               .SelectMany(devr => devr.ValidationErrors)
               .GroupBy(ve => ve.PropertyName)
               .ToDictionary(ve => ve.Key, ve => ve.Select(v => v.ErrorMessage));
```

Comment: Yeah I agree with you this is a better approach, but I'm using dotnet core which to my knowledge does not have GetValidationErrors